# Como alterar o texto dos botões de paginação do UI Bootstrap Pagination?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Estou trabalhando com o [UI Bootstrap Pagination](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap), porém por padrão a linguagem está em inglês.

Seria possível alterar sem ter que modificar o Javascript diretamente? Se sim, poderia me dar um exemplo simples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608794/translate-angular-ui-pagination#19608973), você pode configurar globalmente através do objeto que configura o *UI Bootstrap Paginator* através do `paginationConfig`, conforme abaixo:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.run(function(paginationConfig){
   paginationConfig.firstText = 'Primeiro';
   paginationConfig.previousText = 'Anterior';

})
```

Ná propria documentação também é possível perceber que é possível fazer essa configurações através dos atributos passados em `uib-pagination`.

São eles:

- `first-text`: O texto do botão que vai pra primeira página
- `last-text` : o texto do botão que vai pra última página
- `previous-text` : o texto do botão que volta uma página
- `next-text` : o texto do botão que avança uma página

Exemplo:

```
<ul uib-pagination first-text="Primeiro" previous-text="Voltar"></ul>
```

Basta colocar os valores desejados para ficar na linguagem desejada.

**Nota**: essa última forma afeta apenas a configuração local. Se o desejo for deixar a tradução global, faça através do `paginationConfig`;

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Eu li a documentação mas devo não ter entendido mto bem! Agora ficou claro. Vlww